# Adding a new line for every Div tag

Tags: css, html

I am building a navagation bar and i am making a seprate div tag for each link so I can specify their margin-left because it is a horizontal bar.

Yet when I add the `<div>` tags it puts the next one on the next line:

```
<div>HOME</div>
<div>ABOUT</div>
<div>MUSIC</div>
<div>CONTACT</div>
```

That prints:

```
HOME
ABOUT
MUSIC
CONTACT
```

Yet when I remove them it prints

```
HOME ABOUT MUSIC CONTACT
```

How can I keep it horizontal and yet still style them.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will simply changing the `<div>`'s to `<span>`'s work?

Otherwise, add `style="float:left;"` to the divs.

Comment: You should take note of the point in Jakub's answer though that really your styles should be applied in a seperate stylesheet, and as skajfes is describing in his, understand the difference between block and inline elements.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for is:

In your style sheet (style.css for instance):

```
.nav_button {
    display: inline;
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div class="nav_button">
   HOME
</div>
```

By default they are `display: block;`

**Edited** for Brian Rose so that it is in a style sheet and not inline as per my quick example.

Comment: Why not just make them spans though?

Comment: I'm not sure encouraging using inline styles is a great thing. This belongs in a separate stylesheet file.

Comment: @Brian Rose:  okay.. just for you

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `float: left` you can always try `display: inline-block`. This should have the desired effect :-)

Comment: The only reason to use inline block would be for spacing correct?  I think it's worth determining which styles he wants to use.  If it's color and text-decoration, inline-block is overkill IMO

Comment: Personally, I think it's a better alternative to `float`, because `float` is displayed differently in some browsers sometimes. It also keeps the problems sometimes associated with `float` at bay.

Answer (score 1):

So, div is a block element, by default a block element ocupies maximum width of the container. Span on the other hand is an inline element. Inline elements are stacked, well - inline. 
Inline elements can't have margins, width or height defined, while block elements can. As always with css you have several options:

You can use `float: left` on the div's to stack them horizontally. Remember to add another element at the end with `clear:left` defined so it displays properly accross browsers, and so that the parent container gets height displayed according to the menu items height.

Second option is to use `display: inline-block` which will make the div's stack horizontally but will allow you to define margins, width and height. This however doesn't work in IE6/7 so you'll have to apply `display: inline` for those browsers. The easiest way is the hack `*display: inline`, which is ignored by everything except IE6/7.

Third options is using one of first two options but instead of div's use `<ul>`. You can remove the dots by applying `list-style-type: none` to `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add some CSS:

```
float: left
width: xxx
```

For each DIV or in a class.

Answer (score 0):

You want `<span>` tags, spans are for inline text where as a div is a block element which is why it puts everything on a new line. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using an unordered list (ul) for navigation.
Divs are great for larger sections or boxes but lists are perfect for a list of navigational links.

To do so with your example:

**CSS**

```
 li { display: inline: padding: 4px 8px;}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>MUSIC</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
</ul>
```

also if its for navigation you'd have a tags too:

**html**

```
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MUSIC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, just out of curiosity have you considered using `<li>` tags instead?
something like this.

```
<style>
.nav{
width:20%;
background-color:gray;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
display:inline;
}
.nav li{
width:100%;
}
.nav li a{
background-color:silver;
color:white;
float:left;
padding:7px;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}

</style>
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please let us know if there is a specific reason why you like to use , however I believe using `div` should be just as easy.